# How to combine images with boost gil?

Tags: c++, image-processing, boost, boost-gil

I am just getting familiar with Boost GIL (and image processing in general) and suspect that this is simple, but I haven't found the relevant documentation.

I have a set of image views that I would like to combine with an arbitrary function. For simplicity, lets say the images are aligned (same size and locator type) and I just want to add the pixel values together. One approach would be to [create a combining iterator from a zip_iterator and a transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html), but I'm guessing that there are image processing algorithms that are conveniently abstracted for this purpose.

The [Mandelbrot example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/gil/example/mandelbrot.cpp) in the documentation is probably relevant, because it computes pixel values from a function, but I'm getting lost in the details and having trouble adapting it to my case.

Comment: combine pixel values, how? Combining images had me thinking you want them tiled, offset or as a collage.

Comment: @sehe I mean for each pixel of the result to be a function of corresponding pixels from the input layers. For example, I might want img1 + img2/img3, calculated pixel-by-pixel. Ultimately, I might want to implement this with boost compute, because this arithmetic will be repeated many times and it should be parallelized, but a simple solution is what I need to start.

Comment: Boost compute hinges on memory layout if you ask me. So be prepared to adapt your own custom pixel/locator models. Looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only binary channel algorithm I can find is `channel_multiply`.

The algorithm you're probably really looking for is [`transform_pixels`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/gil/doc/html/g_i_l_0154.html#gceacc4e2452d2b3adba5902b21c5957b) which *does* combine in a binary variation.

Here's the simplest example I could make.

```
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png_io.hpp>

namespace gil = boost::gil;

int main() {
    using Img = gil::rgba8_image_t;
    using Pix = Img::value_type;
    Img a, b;
    gil::png_read_image("/tmp/a.png", a);
    gil::png_read_image("/tmp/b.png", b);

    assert(a.dimensions() == b.dimensions());
    Img c(a.dimensions());

    gil::transform_pixels(view(a), view(b), view(c), [](gil::rgba8_ref_t a, gil::rgba8_ref_t b) {
            gil::red_t   R;
            gil::green_t G;
            gil::blue_t  B;
            gil::alpha_t A;
            return Pix (
                    get_color(a, R) + get_color(b, R),
                    get_color(a, G) + get_color(b, G),
                    get_color(a, B) + get_color(b, B),
                    get_color(a, A) + get_color(b, A)
                );
            });

    gil::png_write_view("/tmp/c.png", view(c));
}
```

When a.png is [image] and b.png is [image] (note transparencies too), c.png became [image] (again, note the transparencies).

You will want to fine-tune the transformation function to do something more useful suppose.